# understanding regular expression for detecting string

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I encountered this regular expression that detects string literal of Unicode characters in JavaScript.

```
'"'("\\x"[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|"\\u"[a-fA-F0-9]{4}|"\\"[^xu]|[^"\n\\])*'"'
```

but I couldn't understand the role and need of

1. `"\\x"[a-fA-F0-9]{2}`
2. `"\\"[^xu]|[^"\n\\]`

My guess about 1) is that it is detecting control characters.

Comment: Hi Rohit and welcome to StackOverflow! I think you need to edit your question and re-paste your regex exactly as you originally have it, then use the `{}` (code) button to format it as code. If you try to out-guess the markdown parser by inserting backslashes yourself, you're making it hard for us to help you. Also something looks wrong about all those quotes in your regex. This question unfortunately is pretty much unanswerable in its current state. You might also want to read the FAQ in the top right of this page. That might help get you started.

Comment: @TimPietzcker thanks for the suggestion, I have edited the original question.
I understand them individually but in combination, they are confusing me.

Comment: Are all those quote characters really there in the original regex? I highly doubt that.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I saw this in a lexical analyzer's lex file. which is used on a javascript parser jison

Comment: That would explain the extra quotes.  It also mean this isn't really a regex, but it's close enough for our purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"\\x"[a-fA-F0-9]{2}
```

This is a literal `\x` followed by two characters from the hex-digit group.

This matches the shorter-form character escapes for the code points 0–255, `\x00`–`\xFF`. These are valid in JavaScript string literals but they aren't in JSON, where you have to use `\u0000`–`\u00FF` instead.

```
"\\"[^xu]|[^"{esc}\n]
```

This matches one of:

1. backslash followed by one more character, except for `x` or `u`. The valid cases for `\xNN` and `\uNNNN` were picked up in the previous `|`-separated clauses, so what this does is avoid matching invalid syntax like `\uqX`.
2. anything else, except for the `"` or newline. It is probably also supposed to be excluding other escape characters, which I'm guessing is what `{esc}` means. That isn't part of the normal regex syntax, but it may be some extended syntax or templating over the top of regex. Otherwise, `[^"{esc}\n]` would mean just any character except `"`, `{`, `e`, `s`, `c`, `}` or newline, which would be wrong.

Notably, the last clause, that picks up ‘anything else’, doesn't exclude `\` itself, so you can still have `\uqX` in your string and get a match even though that is invalid in both JSON and JavaScript.

Comment: The `{esc}` looks like something the OP did because the backslashes weren't showing up because he wasn't using code formatting.  I put the backslashes back where they belonged.